# Using weights with glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am fitting a binary response two level model to measure student performance (say pass and fail) using `glmer` from `lme4`. There are a number of covariates.  Covariate 5 in the table below is the method of assessment.  I wish to apply weights to this model so that the data are matched between a treatment and control on covariate 5. The weights have been derived from a matching process using `quickmatch`. The dataset is large and therefore this is the most appropriate matching method computationally. The weights from `quickmatch` sum to 1 for the treatment and 1 for the control. When applying the weights in `glmer` the standard errors are large but the parameter estimates are sensible*. To make the standard errors sensible, given the size of the dataset, I thought it might be appropriate to scale the weights to reflect the size of the dataset. I rerun the model and sure enough the standard errors are smaller but the parameter estimates have also changed. They still seem sensisble but I don't understand why changing weights by a scalar value should change the parameter estimates.

```
             Quickmatch weight     Scaled weight    
            Estimate Std. Error Estimate Std. Error
Intercept    0.92216    3.61177  0.96941    0.02972
Covariate1   0.09363    3.99407  0.10846    0.03004
Covariate2   2.27514    3.32276  2.42744    0.02508
Covariate3  -0.03241    2.02241 -0.03927    0.01899
Covariate4  -0.43783    5.90232 -0.48611    0.04424
Covariate5  -0.27863    3.99966 -0.28036    0.03127
```

I have used weights with linear multilevel models before and have not encountered this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

*Where I use the term sensible, I mean in line with my expectations given other analyses I have performed on the data.